# How to get the optimal number of neighboors for KNN

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

```
score_array = 0
for each in range(1,25):
    knn_loop = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = each)
#set K neighbor as 3
    knn_loop.fit(X_train,y_train)
    result = knn_loop.score(X_test, y_test)
    if result > score_array:
        score_array = result
    print(score_array)
```

I am inputting the code above, and I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

What can I do to be able to store the maximum number of neighbors?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your error - I ran your code and it does work - score array is indeed an integer so it works.

I'm slightly confused by naming - `score_array` is an integer, perhaps you would prefer to start it as an empty list and then add scores to it?

```
score_array = []
score_threshold = 0
for each in range(1,25):
    knn_loop = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = each)
#set K neighbor as 3
    knn_loop.fit(X_train,y_train)
    result = knn_loop.score(X_test, y_test)
    if result > score_threshold:
        score_array.append(result)
print(score_array)
```